# Div's not lining up properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="calendar">
    <div class="column" id="time_slots">
    </div>

        <div class="column" id="day1">
            <div class="route_container">
                <div class="date"></div>
                <button class="add_route" name="add_route" onclick="">Add New Route - 1</button>
                <div class = "truck" id="day1_route1">
                    <div class="ts8-10">J Smith</div>
                    <div class="ts10-12">10-12 AM</div>
                    <div class="ts12-2">12-2 AM</div>
                    <div class="ts2-4">2-4 AM</div>
                    <div class="ts4-6">4-6 AM</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.label
{
    width:20px;
}

.table
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
#main
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black; 
    width:97%;
    height:900px;
    margin:auto;
    overflow: auto; 
    white-space: nowrap;

}
h2
{
    font-size: 24px;
}
#calendar
{
    padding:1%;

}
.column
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black; 
    min-width:10%;
    max-width:100%;
    width:17%;
    height:1000px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:5px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
.header
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align: center; 
    font-style: bold; 
}
.route_container
{
    height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0px; 


    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black; 
    min-width:10%;
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:5px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
.truck
{
    width:275px;
    height:100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black; 
    display:inline-block;
    margin:auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding:2%;

    position: relative;
}

.column#time_slots
{
    width:5%;
    min-width:5%;
    max-width: 10%; 
}
.date
{
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black; 
}
.column button
{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    width:100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black; 
    font-size: 16px; 
}
.full_time
{
    display: none; 
}

.ts8-10, .ts10-12, .ts12-2, .ts2-4, .ts4-6
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black; 
    width:90%;
    height:20%;
    font-size: 28px; 
    text-align: center;
    padding:5px;    
}
```

I am adding another div with the following Javascript:

```
$(".add_route").click(function(){
        var truck = $(this).parent().find('.truck').length
        truck += 1; 
        var w = $(this).parent().width();
        $(this).parent().animate({width:(w+405)}, 1000);
        $(this).parent().parent().animate({width:(w+425)}, 1000);
        $(this).parent().append('<div class = "truck" id="'+$(this).parent().parent().attr('id')+'_route'+truck+'"><p>There are '+ truck +' routes</p></div>');
        $('#'+$(this).parent().attr('id')+'_route'+truck).hide();


        var route_num = $(this).parent().find('.truck').length;
        var route_w = (100/route_num)-1;        

        $('#'+$(this).parent().attr('id')+'_route'+truck).fadeIn(200);

        $(this).parent().parent().css("padding", "5px"); 
        console.log($(this).parent().parent().css("padding", "5px"))
        $(this).parent().find('.truck').css("margin-right", "3px"); 
   });
```

And I get the following result:

[image]

As you can see, the added div (the one with "there are 2 routes"), is quite a bit lower than the other div. To make matters worse, when I change the contents of this HTML by expanding the divs (ts8-10, etc) and a border:

```
<div class = "truck" id="day1_route1">
                    <div class="ts8-10">J Smith</div>
                    <div class="ts10-12">10-12 AM</div>
                    <div class="ts12-2">12-2 AM</div>
                    <div class="ts2-4">2-4 AM</div>
                    <div class="ts4-6">4-6 AM</div>
                </div>
```

The offset is so much worse. It is practically at the bottom of the first div (the one with JSmith).

I understand this these are set as "inline-block" and I have tried to make adjustments, as you can see, and nothing seems to work. I have checked to make sure that there are no extra margins or padding issues, at least none are showing when I use the Chrome web dev tool.

Can someone tell me what is going on here? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: As above comment, here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/epZts/

Comment: Can you narrow down this question at all? This wall of css is scaring me.

Comment: You're basically fashioning a makeshift table out of divs, which is a lot of work. Just use a table.

Comment: Wholly border-lines Batman!

Comment: Why so many divs? Looks like you are trying to organize the view in rows and colums, if so I would either use a table or less divs.

Comment: @Reconstruct, make your comment an answer, and I'll accept. JHuangweb I use the borders to see the divs. They all go away when I'm done... LOL..Portu, I think you're right, I'll probably put a table in truck column. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`inline-block` items are aligned based on the `vertical-align` property, which defaults to `baseline`. Add `vertical-align:top;` to `.truck`.

(This is a more flexible, intuitive solution than using a `table-cell` hack. `inline-block` will still behave as you expect it to after that.)

Answer (score 0):

In css change the display :inline-block to table-cell, It will work

```
.truck
{
  width:275px;
  height:100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black; 
  /*display: inline-block;*/

  display: table-cell;

  margin:auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding:2%;
  position: relative;
}
```